# What is this machine learning algorithm called?

Tags: machine-learning

I was reading this webpage which was describing an example of how Naive Bayes classification works:

http://www.statsoft.com/textbook/naive-bayes-classifier

Their example involves looking at the probability of a class given other points in the sample's *vicinity*.

This looks like some sort of hybrid of naive bayes and k-Nearest-Neighbors. Is this true and is this truly the naive bayes algorithm, or is this some new algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: If you read past the introductory overview, they later call that section an "intuitive example". It's a bad metaphor. Especially if, say, you're thinking about how to use the approach to classify email spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is not how a naive bayes classifier work in any way, how ever it's not taken from thin air.

Under certain assumptions (like that the naive bayes is a perfect model for the data and infinite amount of data) we have that the

"number of COLOR in vicinity X/number of COLOR"

is the

"density of COLOR near X"

which is proportional to `p(x|COLOR)`

so finally `p(COLOR|x) <proportional to> p(x|COLOR)p(COLOR)`

It shows a relation between the kNN algorithm and naive bayes but nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is any other algorithm. It is clearly naive Bayes classifier. He took some possible example to explain the concept.